# Binding Company Name to dropdownlist in Updatepanel and Autocomplete TextBox working But Every time Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, autocomplete

I know everyone asking same question. But I searched but did not get Answer....
In UpdatePanel I Used CompanyName dropdownlist and Autocomplete TextBox to Bind Guest UserName It's Working.....

But When I use `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger.....>` AutoComplete is not work.
`<asp:PostBackTrigger.....>` Autocompete Work but Page refresh every time. 
Problem is : Every time Refresh the page. How to solve this problem..Please Help me ...

code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompany" class="select_width" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
.
.
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Code :

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(SetAutoCompleteGuest());

       // $(document).ready(function () {
    function SetAutoCompleteGuest() {

            $(".autoguest").autocomplete({
                // source: "AutoGuest.ashx"

                source: function (request, response) {
                    var customer = new Array();
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "AutoGuest.ashx?ClCompId=<%=ddlCompany.SelectedValue %>&Comp_Id=<%=Comp_Id.Text%>",
                        success: function (data) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                                customer[i] = {
                                    label: data[i].label,
                                    //  id: data[i].id,
                                    Value: data[i].Value,
                                    Email: data[i].Email
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    response(customer);
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("[id$=txtMobileNo]").attr('value', ui.item.Value);
                    //  $("#hdnVndrChuf_Id").attr('value', ui.item.id);
                    $("[id$=txtNameOfGuest]").attr('value', ui.item.label);
                    $("[id$=txtEmail]").attr('value', ui.item.Email);
                }
            });
       }

   // });
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to call `response(customer);` in success callback (after for loop) not outside.

Comment: Welcome to SO if you want to add code indent it with 4 spaces or use `{}` button.

Comment: Sir,  It's not working... When I use AutoPostBack="True".

Comment: This was not the answer to the question, just a comment about the code you have. That's why I use comment.

Comment: thanks....when i call postback event like on dropdown and other event in update panel after calling  that autocomplete not working. so how can rebind my jquery function to auto complete textbox.

Comment: Try passing the function to `add_pageLoaded` `getInstance().add_pageLoaded(SetAutoCompleteGuest);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncPostBackTrigger and set async: true.

Thanks

Comment: Where should I put async:true.

Comment: It is already in your $.ajax function as false, change this to true.